# how to change the color of CheckBox square?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, checkbox, android-xml

I want to change the colour of Square box of checkbox, not the colour of text, only that square image in which we tick.

Answer (score 10):

You can color directly in the xml. Use buttonTint for the checkbox

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:buttonTint="@color/lightColoral"
    />
```

The below code works on API < 21

```
app:buttonTint="@color/lightColoral"
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 2):

### You can use AppCompat Checkbox and use app:buttonTint="@color/yellow".

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                app:buttonTint="@color/yellow"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom theme for the checkbox

```
<style name="CheckBoxTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme

```
<style name="CheckBoxTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

then in xml write next :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:theme="@style/CheckBoxTheme"/>
```

For API 21+ should be use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:buttonTint="@color/blue"/>
```